# URI ROUTING in CodeIgnitor_2.1.3 throwing "Not Found" error

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2, wampserver

I have installed **CodeIgniter_2.1.3**  and running in

- Windows 7
- Wamp Server 2.1
- PHP 5.3.5
- Apache 2.2.17

In **\applicationconfig\routes.php**, I created

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['products/catlog'] = "welcome/getOneMethod";
```

And in **\application\controllers\welcome.php**, I created a method

```
    public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}

public function getOneMethod()
{
        echo "hi im in newMethod";
}
```

> `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/products/catlog`

Now I expect on running this url above on browser to give me the page

> hi im in newMethod

But instead i'm getting the error message.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /CodeIgniter_2.1.3/products/catlog was not found on
>   this server.

What should i do to make it work correctly?

Comment: http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/products/catlog  Try with this url

Comment: i was wondering that is it anything to do with xamp or php or apache configurations

Comment: http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/welcome/getOneMethod

Comment: no now showing welcome message

Comment: What is your class name in welcome.php?

Answer (score 0):

Doo you visit codeigniter documentation website,You can get help from this url how to create static pages

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: always defalt contorl is working.other methods from control is not accepting

Comment: did you try redirect using htaccess

Comment: yes i did as Standardspecification told, but now the page is showing "Welcome to CodeIgniter!" instead of running  getOneMethod

Answer (score 0):

For the given url routes and controller.

you will need to use:

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/products/catlog/
```

The index.php part in the url can be removed using htaccess rewrite rule.

In the /codeigniter2.1.3/ folder create an .htaccess file and put the following rule:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_2.1.3/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Note: This might not be the best way to do it.

EDIT:

Make sure the controller is exactly as bellow,

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function getOneMethod() {
        echo "hi im in newMethod";
    }

}
```

and the routes are as bellow:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['products/catlog'] = "welcome/getOneMethod";
```

For the time being remove the htacces, and make it work with index.php in url.

ie:

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/products/catlog/
```

Note: since you are able to see the welcome message, there is no problem with your installation or server. there is probably some syntax error. so i recommend you copy paste the above code, as i have checked them and they are working.

Comment: why don't you rename the 'CodeIgniter_2.1.3' folder to something easier to type?

Comment: @stdspec, first i tried the `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/products/catlog/` but it now shows the "Welcome to CodeIgniter!" message.

Comment: 2nd i did create the .htaccess file but still pointing to "Welcome to CodeIgniter!" message when try this url `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/products/catlog/`.

Comment: @stdspec i didnt rename 'CodeIgniter_2.1.3' because it was just a fresh installation.